# indenting text several pixels on every line

Tags: actionscript-3

Does anyone have any idea how to indent text on every line? I am alligning my text to the border of my movieclip wich has a diagonal border. So when i add my text it should indent for example: 2px on line 2, 4px on line 3, 6 on line 4, 8 on line 5, etc. Would there be an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
 private var newFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
 newFormat.indent = 20;
```

Alternatively, you can view it at the adobe live site itself.

[TextFormat](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextFormat.html#TextFormat%28%29) class is what you will need for this. Example for the [indent](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextFormat.html#indent) function of the TextFormat class can be found in the example of the TextFormat constructor implementation.

Comment: but isnt this gonna indent every line more and more? i think this is for the first line of the paragraph but i want every line indented 2 pixels more than the previous line